# What are some ways to speed up cufon's load time?

Tags: javascript, fonts, cufon, font-replacement

I'm using cufon for font replacement with jQuery for a site built on-top of drupal with a couple modules that tack on its own JS files.  There seems to be a flicker in the text that I have cufon applied to.  I'm profiling my JS in firebug and it looks like cufon is taking forever to load.

A couple things that I've tried:

- adding cufon.now before the closing body tag
- moved any cufon.replace from within $(document).ready() to including the bit of JS right after that element on the page.

None of that seems to be helping the delay.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Sure there is, add this just before `</body>` tag:

`<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.now();
</script>`

Cufon.now will speed up the font loading, as well as prevent "flickering"